# Scala: Compilation error: Overloaded method

Tags: scala, java-8, playframework, sbt, jooq

I imported to Intellij a Play/Scala project with [the following method call](https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/reactive-web-applications/blob/b3b2df93f5fc998a6d61a17c553dbae349537970/CH07/app/actors/CQRSEventHandler.scala#L21) that gets a compilation error for a reason which I do not understand.

**What is the reason for this compilation error?**

**Shouldn't the compiler be able to choose the correct overloaded method?**

I am using Java 8, Scala 2.11.7, Play 2.4.3, JOOQ 3.7.1, SBT 0.13.18.

```
  def receive = {
    case UserRegistered(phoneNumber, userName, timestamp) =>
      database.withTransaction { sql =>
        sql.insertInto(TWITTER_USER)
          .columns(TWITTER_USER.CREATED_ON, TWITTER_USER.PHONE_NUMBER, TWITTER_USER.TWITTER_USER_NAME)
          //THE FOLLOWING METHOD CALL HAS A COMPILATION ERROR:
          .values(new Timestamp(timestamp.getMillis), phoneNumber, userName)
          .execute()
      }
    case ClientEvent(phoneNumber, userName, MentionsSubscribed(timestamp), _) =>
      database.withTransaction { sql =>
        sql.insertInto(MENTION_SUBSCRIPTIONS)
          .columns(MENTION_SUBSCRIPTIONS.USER_ID, MENTION_SUBSCRIPTIONS.CREATED_ON)
          .select(
             select(TWITTER_USER.ID, value(new Timestamp(timestamp.getMillis)))
               .from(TWITTER_USER)
               .where(
                 TWITTER_USER.PHONE_NUMBER.equal(phoneNumber)
                 .and(
                   TWITTER_USER.TWITTER_USER_NAME.equal(userName)
                 )
               )
          ).execute()
      }
    case ClientEvent(phoneNumber, userName, MentionReceived(id, created_on, from, text, timestamp), _) =>
      database.withTransaction { sql =>
        sql.insertInto(MENTIONS)
          .columns(
            MENTIONS.USER_ID,
            MENTIONS.CREATED_ON,
            MENTIONS.TWEET_ID,
            MENTIONS.AUTHOR_USER_NAME,
            MENTIONS.TEXT
          )
          .select(
             select(
               TWITTER_USER.ID,
               value(new Timestamp(timestamp.getMillis)),
               value(id),
               value(from),
               value(text)
             )
             .from(TWITTER_USER)
             .where(
               TWITTER_USER.PHONE_NUMBER.equal(phoneNumber)
               .and(
                 TWITTER_USER.TWITTER_USER_NAME.equal(userName)
               )
             )
          ).execute()
      }
  }
```

As you can see, the method call `.values(new Timestamp(timestamp.getMillis), phoneNumber, userName)` has a compilation error. The error output is:

```
[info] Compiling 30 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/me/projects/book/CH07/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/me/projects/book/CH07/app/actors/CQRSEventHandler.scala:21: overloaded method value values with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: org.jooq.Field[java.time.OffsetDateTime],x$2: org.jooq.Field[String],x$3: org.jooq.Field[String])org.jooq.InsertValuesStep3[generated.tables.records.TwitterUserRecord,java.time.OffsetDateTime,String,String] <and>
[error]   (x$1: java.time.OffsetDateTime,x$2: String,x$3: String)org.jooq.InsertValuesStep3[generated.tables.records.TwitterUserRecord,java.time.OffsetDateTime,String,String]
[error]  cannot be applied to (java.sql.Timestamp, String, String)
[error]           .values(new Timestamp(timestamp.getMillis), phoneNumber, userName)
[error]            ^
[error] /home/me/projects/book/CH07/app/actors/CQRSEventHandler.scala:31: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.jooq.SelectConditionStep[org.jooq.Record2[Long,java.sql.Timestamp]]
[error]  required: org.jooq.Select[_ <: org.jooq.Record2[Long,java.time.OffsetDateTime]]
[error]                .where(
[error]                      ^
[error] /home/me/projects/book/CH07/app/actors/CQRSEventHandler.scala:58: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.jooq.SelectConditionStep[org.jooq.Record5[Long,java.sql.Timestamp,String,String,String]]
[error]  required: org.jooq.Select[_ <: org.jooq.Record5[Long,java.time.OffsetDateTime,String,String,String]]
[error]              .where(
[error]                    ^
[error] /home/me/projects/book/CH07/app/actors/CQRSQueryHandler.scala:29: overloaded method value greaterOrEqual with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: org.jooq.QuantifiedSelect[_ <: org.jooq.Record1[java.time.OffsetDateTime]])org.jooq.Condition <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.jooq.Select[_ <: org.jooq.Record1[java.time.OffsetDateTime]])org.jooq.Condition <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.jooq.Field[java.time.OffsetDateTime])org.jooq.Condition <and>
[error]   (x$1: java.time.OffsetDateTime)org.jooq.Condition
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.jooq.Field[java.sql.Timestamp])
[error]         MENTIONS.CREATED_ON.greaterOrEqual(currentDate().cast(PostgresDataType.TIMESTAMP))
[error]                             ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application - 

! @7fjed5mfe - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[Overloaded method value [values] cannot be applied to  (java.sql.Timestamp, String, String)]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
```

The overloaded methods in `org.jooq.InsertValuesStep3 (3.7.1)` :

```
package org.jooq;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

/**
 * This type is used for the {@link Insert}'s DSL API.
 * <p>
 * Example: <code><pre>
 * using(configuration)
 *       .insertInto(table, field1, field2, field3)
 *       .values(field1, field2, field3)
 *       .values(field1, field2, field3)
 *       .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
 *       .set(field1, value1)
 *       .set(field2, value2)
 *       .execute();
 * </pre></code>
 *
 * @author Lukas Eder
 */
@Generated("This class was generated using jOOQ-tools")
public interface InsertValuesStep3<R extends Record, T1, T2, T3> extends InsertOnDuplicateStep<R> {

    /**
     * Add values to the insert statement.
     */
    @Support
    InsertValuesStep3<R, T1, T2, T3> values(T1 value1, T2 value2, T3 value3);

    /**
     * Add values to the insert statement.
     */
    @Support
    InsertValuesStep3<R, T1, T2, T3> values(Field<T1> value1, Field<T2> value2, Field<T3> value3);

    /**
     * Add values to the insert statement.
     */
    @Support
    InsertValuesStep3<R, T1, T2, T3> values(Collection<?> values);

    /**
     * Use a <code>SELECT</code> statement as the source of values for the
     * <code>INSERT</code> statement
     * <p>
     * This variant of the <code>INSERT .. SELECT</code> statement expects a
     * select returning exactly as many fields as specified previously in the
     * <code>INTO</code> clause:
     * {@link DSLContext#insertInto(Table, Field, Field, Field)}
     */
    @Support
    InsertOnDuplicateStep<R> select(Select<? extends Record3<T1, T2, T3>> select);
}
```

Comment: You already asked a question about this project not compiling with a method overloaded error yesterday. This is the same question. Please don't post duplicate questions. There's clearly something wrong with the build of this project. Not surprising perhaps, since it's old. Possible problems, you're using an incompatible version of java/scala/sbt which conflicts with the dependencies of the project. These questions really belong on the issue page on github

Comment: I do not post duplicate questions. You have no right to tell me which project to work on. It's legitimate to ask about older projects, especially if am aware that I need to replicate the original dependencies. Not that it matters, but there is no newer version of this book yet, and the actual projects are valuable. I have enough experience to know that even if I want to upgrade the dependencies, I 1st have to get the original code to work. It's too simplistic to conclude that two questions are the same because it's the same project and same compiler error: compiler error is often just symptom.

Comment: it was not my intention to suggest you cannot work on this project. It seems interesting and it's probably useful to others to get it working. The way I read this question is, why am I getting  method overloaded compilation errors for this project. To me that is the same question as the other question you asked about another method overloaded compilation error in the same project. I agree that it's symptomatic of another issue, which is why I believe the question is better asked as a general question of building a project with a specific scala/sbt version with a certain sbt config

Comment: It's entirely incorrect that on SO you are allowed to ask a question "how do I build this project (which has multiple points that need correction)?". Nobody would try to answer it and it would be downvoted and deleted (happens even when questions are legitimate and properly written). Questions need to be specific, they need to isolate a specific problem as much as possible, they need to show that the OP did their homework, i.e. that they tried their best to resolve the problem but they reached a dead-end. P.S. Mathematically, 80% of the people work on "old code" at every point in time.

Answer (score 0):

The overloading messages are confusing, but the real problem is that the code is passing a `java.sql.Timestamp` where a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` is required. They are not compatible types.

Comment: How to create a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from `org.joda.time.DateTime` or `java.sql.Timestamp`?